# How to add addtional source directories in vscode when debugging c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have some third party libraries for my application and source files of those libraries.Is there any way to add those directories to vscode when debugging?

I thought [sourceFileMap](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_sourcefilemap) may do this job but did't figure out how to configure this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have release distribution or debug distribution of your "libraries" ?

Comment: @Landstalker Does this matter?I compiled those libraries, so I have debug and release version.

Comment: it seems important, because we cannot debug a release version, unless the library was built with `.pdb`. Why you don't just add your code to your solution as new project, and add dependency? or if you have already generated your libs a single project, add this project to your main project

Comment: We have a dependency on [VTK](https://vtk.org/), and its a huge library.For some reason we compiled this library as a static library(*.lib on windows) separately using cmake and link it to our executable file.May be I will add vtk to our main sulution and  compile this library myself.

Comment: Ok, i understand. juste a suggestion : in your place, i generate a solution of my library using CMake, I add my executable project to this solution, add VTK dependency. I will have a solution containing two projects : my executable AND static library project. this allows you to debug